# Visual Studio can't "find all references", but can "find in files"

Tags: visual-studio-2019

Visual Studio 2019 Pro, v. 16.11.13.

A Solution with about 100 projects. All projects are included in the build process. Solution was opened about a half an hour ago, and was just fully rebuilt.

I'm clicking on some const field and choose "Find All References" - nothing was found, except the "Symbols without references". Then I'm trying to find this field through "Find in Files", and it found me a reference to this field inside some Razor page. Checked - there are no broken references. The project, that references to this field, has reference to the project, that contains this field.

But! After opening the Razor page with this field, now it can find this field through "Find All References".

What? Why? For what reason?

Comment: `inside some Razor page` - this is why. Those are invisible and cannot be refactored too.

Comment: Is it a bug or for a purpose?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/find-all-references-doesnt-find-references-in-csht/32170. MS says it's fixed, people are commenting that it isn't.

Comment: Thank you. So it is a bug. Good addition - "unless they are open in the editor" - it happend with me also.